# Load Multiple URN in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I use ver.2.5 viewer.js. I can load three rvt model (a building, split each three floor to a model) in one viewer, and it fits perfectly.

After I switch to the newest viewer.js (v.2.10), three rvt model will overlap each other.

I check the difference between the v2.5 viewer and v2.10 viewer, and V2.5 has following code:

```
//If there is already a model loaded, we need to use the same globaOffset as the first model,
//with the assumption that multiple models are loaded into the same space (more or less).

if (this.viewer3DImpl.model && !options.globalOffset) {
  options.globalOffset = this.viewer3DImpl.model.getData().globalOffset;
}
```

How can I get the same result as v2.5 viewer without editing the source of 2.10 viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

Now, since 2.7, you have to get the globalOffset from your first model and create a globalOffset option to insert in your loadModel query.

```
var globalOffset = viewer.model.getData().globalOffset; //Get it from first model
var options = {globalOffset: globalOffset}
viewer.loadModel(path, options); //Load your second model
```

Comment: This kinda makes sense to me, one may not want necessarily to insert the extra model at the same position than the first one, so it gives more flexibility